# Mysql2::Error: All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created a demo application in `rails 3.2.9` and `ruby versiion 2.0.0` . After scaffolding Blog model I am trying to migrate it, but having following issue.

> # rake db:migrate
>
> ==  CreateBlogs: migrating ====================================================
>
> -- create_table(:blogs) 
>   rake aborted!
>
> StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:
>
> Mysql2::Error: All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead: CREATE TABLE `blogs` (`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `title` varchar(255), `description` text, `created_at` datetime NOT NULL, `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648@demo-app/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `query'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648@demo-app/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in`block in execute'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648@demo-app/gems/activerecord-

....

....

....

> -3.2.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648@demo-app/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:179:in`block (2 levels) in '
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648@demo-app/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `'
>   Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
>   (See full trace by running task with --trace)

Answer (score 53):

Add this initializer to fix the problem:

`config/initializers/abstract_mysql2_adapter.rb`

```rb
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter'

class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter
    NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:primary_key] = "int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY"
end
```

Comment: the require line should be `require 'active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter'` in Rails 3.2.22.5.  Background on why this issue exists in Rails3 is here: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/784#issuecomment-414878642

Comment: Following only this answer did not fix this for me. However, I found this reported [issue on git](https://github.com/peatio/peatio/issues/590). Found this line from comments which solved my problem. 
After doing above you need to add following line in your **envrionment.rb** file.
require File.expand_path('../initializers/abstract_mysql2_adapter', __FILE__).
I hope it will help someone to fix this issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too (mysql 0.3.21 and Rails 3.2.22.5).
I fixed it by adding a file in my application `config/initializers/mysql2_adapter.rb` (as there was no such file before) with the below content:

```rb
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter'
class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter
  NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:primary_key] = "int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY"
end
```

Then, in my `environment.rb` file, I've added below content:

```rb
require File.expand_path('../initializers/mysql2_adapter', __FILE__)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred when ***not null*** is defined with ***primary key*** column.

Even if you defined any ***composite key***, then those column definition does not contains the ***not null*** criteria.

Search for those column, remove the ***not null*** criteria, this is one of the solution to remove the error.

Answer (score -1):

In this line `id int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY` you are creating a primary key (which can never be null), with the default value NULL. 
In your migration file (or schema.rb) you should make sure the `DEFAULT NULL` part is removed.