# ActiveRecord adapter not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

I switched from sqlite to mysql in my rails 3 application. I'm getting the following error when I try to run the server.

`Users/harshkumar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:133:in 'establish_connection': database configuration specifies nonexistent mysql2 adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotFound)`

I have included mysql2 gem in the gemfile. My rails version is 3.2.21 and mysql2 gem version is 0.3.21

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  database: sys
  username: root
  password: 
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: sys
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: ''

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: sys
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: ''
```

This is my database.yml file

update: I got this error when I fixed my pervious problem with this solution: 
[Mysql2::Error: All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758226/mysql2error-all-parts-of-a-primary-key-must-be-not-null-if-you-need-null-in)

Comment: Have you installed MySQL on your computer, created a user, a database and run a `bundle install` after you have added the gem

Comment: yes, rake db:create and rake db:migrate ran fine, able to generate models and can see the models in the schema, just can't run the server