# Mysql2::Error: All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, database-migration

I am using a legacy version of rails 3.2.22 and while trying to execute my migration file, I encountered this error:

```
rake db:migrate
==  CreateBooks: migrating ====================================================
-- create_table(:books)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead: CREATE TABLE `books` (`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `Book Title` varchar(255), `Author` varchar(255), `Date Published` date, `Book ID` int(11), `Checked Out?` tinyint(1), `Return Time` datetime, `created_at` datetime NOT NULL, `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:80:in `_query'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:80:in `block in query'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:79:in `handle_interrupt'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/client.rb:79:in `query'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `block in execute'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `execute'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:213:in `execute'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:170:in `create_table'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:434:in `create_table'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:466:in `block in method_missing'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `say_with_time'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:458:in `method_missing'
/home/elliot/Desktop/SAIT WORK/Library/db/migrate/20220609183208_create_books.rb:3:in `up'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `block in migrate'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:129:in `with_connection'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:389:in `migrate'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in `migrate'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:720:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:777:in `call'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:777:in `ddl_transaction'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:719:in `block in migrate'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `each'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `migrate'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:193:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/rake-12.3.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
```

I am well aware of the fact that people have posted this problem in the past and there have been solutions posted that helped solve this problem but when I attempt to utilize those solutions, I encounter errors. In particular, I am referencing this guide:
[Link to solution 1](https://til.codes/creating-tables-and-problems-with-primary-key-in-rails/)

However, when I implement the suggested changes, I can run the rake db:migrate, however, when I try to run any other rails command (i.e. rails s or rails console), I get this error:

```
rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.22 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- /home/elliot/Desktop/SAIT WORK/Library/lib/patches/abstract_mysql_adapter (LoadError)
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/elliot/Desktop/SAIT WORK/Library/config/environment.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/elliot/Desktop/SAIT WORK/Library/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /home/elliot/Desktop/SAIT WORK/Library/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/elliot/Desktop/SAIT WORK/Library/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I have also tried the implementing the solution suggested here:
[Link to Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758226/mysql2error-all-parts-of-a-primary-key-must-be-not-null-if-you-need-null-in) but I would run into the same error. Could this problem relate to the naming convention of my models and tables? I am very stuck so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**app/models/book.rb**

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

**config/database.yml !!!Note that I omitted the password and username for privacy, but they are implemented correctly I believe!!!**

```
# MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
# 
# Install the MYSQL driver
#   gem install mysql2
#
# Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: Library_development
  pool: 5
  username: **
  password: **
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: Library_test
  pool: 5
  username: **
  password: **
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: Library_production
  pool: 5
  username: **
  password: **
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

**db/migrate/20220609183208_create_books.rb**

```
class CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :books do |t|
      t.string 'Book Title'
      t.string 'Author'
      t.date "Date Published"
      t.integer "Book ID"
      t.boolean "Checked Out?"
      t.datetime "Return Time"
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :books
  end

end
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.22'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

# gem 'mysql2'

gem 'mysql'
gem 'mysql2', "~> 0.3.10"

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'

gem 'devise'

gem 'cancancan'

gem 'mail_interceptor', group: [:development, :staging]

#gem 'sidekiq', '~>6.0.0'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end

gem "bootstrap-sass", "~> 3.1.1.0"
```

Comment: You should only need the money patch for doing the migration. After migration you should remove it, or at least comment it out. Also best to only have one mysql gem included in your Gemfile.

Comment: Adding to the above, NEVER use 2 gems that do the same job, the probability of creating conflicts between them is huge. Also you don't need to remove the "patch", just make sure the file path you're referencing is correct...  Im not sure if it works, but you could try using "#{Rails.root}/lib/patches/abstract_mysql_adapter"